Is there any instance of Sati practice described in Itihasa and Purana?
Was Sati practice (a widow sacrifices herself by sitting atop her deceased husband's funeral pyre) prevalent or rare in Hindu society described in Itihasas, Puranas, Vedas etc? Was it a norm or an exception? That is what I want to know. Do our scriptures mention any instance of Sati? Or did it start or gain popularity in the later period (in historical times)?

As per Vishnu Purana, Krishna's wives, Balarama's wife and Vasudeva's wives committed Sati.

ARJUNA having found the bodies of Kṛṣṇa and of Rāma, performed for
them, and the rest of the slain, the obsequial rites. The eight
queens of Kṛṣṇa, who have been named, with Rukminī at their head,
embraced the body of Hari, and entered the funeral fire.
Revatī also, embracing the corpse of Rāma, entered the blazing pile, which was cool to her, happy in contact with her lord. Hearing
these events, Ugrasena and Anakadundubhi, with Devakī and Rohinī,
committed themselves to the flames.
[Vishnu Purana Book V, Chapter 38]


An instance of Sati is described in the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata. The step-mother of Arjuna, Madri (mother of Nakula and Sahadeva) performed Sati upon the death of King Pandu who was cursed by Kindama rishi.
Below is an excerpt of the discussion which takes place between Madri and Queen Kunti on who would join their husband.

O revered one, if I survive you, it is certain I shall not be able to
rear your children as if they were mine. Will not sin touch me on that
account?
But, you, O Kunti, shall be able to bring my sons up as if they were
thine. The king, in seeking me wishfully, has gone to the region of
spirits; therefore, my body should be burnt with his.
O revered sister, withhold not your sanction to this which is
agreeable to me. You will certainly bring up the children carefully.
That indeed, would be very agreeable to me. I have no other direction
to give!'
"Vaisampayana continued, 'Having said this, the daughter of the king
of Madras, the wedded wife of Pandu, ascended the funeral pyre of her
lord, that bull among men.'"

Another instance of Sati is seen in the Bhagavata Purana where one of the wives of King Bāhuka who had passed away wanted to take to Sati but was forbidden to do so since she was pregnant.

Bāhuka died when he was old, and one of his wives wanted to die with
him, following the satī rite. At that time, however, Aurva Muni,
knowing her to be pregnant, forbade her to die.

